# Extracting the contentUrl from image upload variabl

Tags: image-upload, bot-framework-composer

I can successfully upload an image to my bot, which has a property dialogue.attachments.  Dialogue.attachments looks like this:

“lgType”: “Activity”,

“text”: [

{

"contentType": "image/png",

"contentUrl": "http://localhost:5000/v3/attachments/0e8f3c75-cb9f-4aa0-9a46-0756c3c7a6c9/views/original",

"content": null,

"name": "Test Ankle - Swollen.png",

"thumbnailUrl": null

}
]

}

How do I access the contentUrl into a variable (or "property") so I can use it elsewhere in an image analysis api?  I need to be able to do this from within the Bot Framework Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property - *contentUrl* by using the **getProperty** Object Manipulation function
[image]

e.g. getProperty(obj, "contentUrl")

or using dot notation
obj.contentUrl